# Unable to pass uploaded file from angular to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API method

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to pass uploaded file from angular to an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API method. Currently I'm getting an error

> Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded

I tried below things, but none worked.

1. Tried removing `Content-type` and boundary
2. Added `[FromForm]` to `IFormFile` parameter in API method
3. Tried adding `DisableRequestSizeLimit` to API endpoint

In .NET 6, `Program.cs` file contains this code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) => { options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;   });

builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueCountLimit = 10;
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
    o.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 1024;
});
```

In Angular, I'm using this code:

```
onFileChanged(event:any) {
        debugger
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        let fileToUpload = <File>file;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
      
        this.uploadCustomService.submit(formData).subscribe(res=> {
        });
}
        
submit( uploadFileData: any) { // submit method present in uploadCustomService
      debugger
      const  httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryKKzIqGjXEOcrZXbB' 
          })
      }
       
      return this.http.post("http://localhost:5357/api/FileUpload/Submit",uploadFileData
// { formData : uploadFileData }
       ,httpOptions
        ).pipe(map((res:any)=>res.json()),  
        //retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
        );
      }
```

My API submit method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("Submit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(IFormFile formData)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

I'm able to pass uploaded file through ASP.NET Core 6 Web API swagger, but not from Angular.

Comment: Change the API method signature to: `public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromForm] IFormFile file)`, does it work?

Comment: Tried [FromForm] aswell. Didn't worked.

Comment: Please post the **full** exception `StackTrace`.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` <-- Don't do this, _unless_ you pass `ex` to `ILogger` and then re-throw. You should not use `try/catch` to get error-messages for `BadRequest` - instead use `ModelState`.